# postgresql subquery returning rows when it should fail on invalid column

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

A subquery which I would expect to fail because it references a column which does not exist, actually returns all the rows of the table referenced in the subquery. Is this expected behaviour in postgresql or a postgresql bug?

To simulate the problem:

```
create table zz_temp_01
(
column_a    varchar(20),
column_b    int
)
;

create table zz_temp_02
(
column_c    int,
column_d    varchar(20)
)
;


insert into zz_temp_01
values
('test1', 1),
('test2', 2)
;

insert into zz_temp_02
values
(1, 'Monday'),
(2, 'Tuesday'),
(3, 'Wednesday'),
(4, 'Thursday'),
(5, 'Friday'),
(6, 'Saturday'),
(7, 'Sunday')
;

select * from zz_temp_02
where column_c in
(select column_c from zz_temp_01)
;
```

This query is clearly incorrect since the subquery references column_c from the table zz_temp_01 when it should have used column_b. Executing "select column_c from zz_temp_01" results in an error: column "column_c" does not exist. However if the whole query is executed, then the result is:

```
1;"Monday"
2;"Tuesday"
3;"Wednesday"
4;"Thursday"
5;"Friday"
6;"Saturday"
7;"Sunday"
```

which is the complete zz_temp_02 table. I would have expected the query to fail on an error condition or at least return no rows.

Comment: No, that's correct. This is how the visibility of identifiers is defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: See here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20151030003924.3017.23003%40wrigleys.postgresql.org#20151030003924.3017.23003@wrigleys.postgresql.org  and here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20160714135233.1410.92538%40wrigleys.postgresql.org#20160714135233.1410.92538@wrigleys.postgresql.org

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the correct behaviour as required by the SQL standard.

For a more detailed explanation see [this mail thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20160714135233.1410.92538%40wrigleys.postgresql.org#20160714135233.1410.92538@wrigleys.postgresql.org)

> A common complaint but unfortunately something that simply has to be
>   learned.
>   The reference to column_c  in the subquery comes from zz_temp_02 - which in
>   this case makes the where clause `(zz_temp_02.column_c IN (zz_temp_02.column_c))`
>   ​which will always evaluate to true.

---

<sup>I replaced the column and table names from the mail thread with the ones from the question, but the quote is otherwise unaltered.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

select * from zz_temp_02
where column_c in
(select column_B from zz_temp_01)
;